Why my reverse will only work if batteryis almost dead
So my question is has anybody had the issue reverse going out on a 2001 Nissan Maxima but I have to say 2002 if I ordered parts because it was made so far at the end of the year but anyways if my battery is almost dead I can Rev it up up to higher RPMs and reverse will work like that but if the battery is fully charged it will not engage at all I don't even know where to start to try to fix this any advice is helpful thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
